# About system requirements

Tags: system-requirements

My computer, a HP d260 MT brand machine has the following specs:

- Pentium 4 processor @3.0 Ghz
- On-board Intel 82865G graphics controller
- 1 GB RAM

Can you tell me please, which version of Ubuntu will work fine on my Pc, and what extra software will I need?

Thank you!

Comment: any older versions may work as i don;t want any lightweight versions

Comment: Older versions are not supported anymore, so I don't think you should use them.

Comment: would xubuntu work fine any will it not have any graphics problem?

Comment: Xubuntu 12.04 32-bit is what you need. It has Long Term Support until April, 2017. Ubuntu would be really slow on your computer.

Comment: It is hard to guess, but I think it will work fine. Older Intel chipset sometimes can be PITA, but usually they are OK.

Comment: @karel Ubuntu don't slow down his pc, just that his pc is too fat for Ubuntu ;)

Comment: I'll be using it only for browsing,watching videos and some programming stuff that i'm learning now, thanks everyone

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a leightweight Ubuntu Verison called Lubuntu. I recommend this one.

[Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/)

Comment: Or you may try [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) too. More heavyweight desktop enviroments are not recommended I think.

Comment: would xubuntu work fine any will it not have any graphics problem?

Comment: can anyone tell me should i choose xubuntu 12.04 or 12.04.2